# atoi() like function in bash?

Tags: bash

Imagine that I use a state file to store a number, I read the number like this:

`COUNT=$(< /tmp/state_file)`

But since the file could be disrupted, $COUNT may not contain a "number", but any characters.

Other than using regex, i.e `if [[ $COUNT ~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then blabla; fi`, is there a "atoi" function that convert it to a number(0 if invalid)?

**EDIT**

Finally I decided to use something like this:

`let a=$(($a+0))`

Or

`declare -i a; a="abcd123"; echo $a # got 0`

Thanks to J20 for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an `atoi` equivalent, Bash variables are untyped. Trying to use variables set to random characters in arithmetic will just silently ignore them. eg

```
foo1=1
foo2=bar
let foo3=foo1+foo2
echo $foo3
```

Gives the result `1`.

See [this reference](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html)

Answer (score 0):

`echo $COUNT | bc` should be able to cast a number, prone to error as per jurgemaister's comments...

`echo ${COUNT/[a-Z]*} | bc` which is similar to your regex method but not prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

```
case "$c" in
[0-9])...
```

You should eat the input string charwise.